# How to deal with temporary problems from largely used external tools

Tags: discussion, support

Maven Central Repository had a temporary problem with certificates yesterday that I ran into. After a few quick checks on my side on my configurations [I posted a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682932/maven-certificate-broken-for-ubuntu-16-04).

Very quickly I got two answers mentioning a workaround and a little while after my question was put on hold as off-topic as a problem that can not be reproduced, with comments pointing to [the sonatype page for the actual problem](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-1369) by @Tunaki, who is an Apache Maven committer and also marked as duplicate a [question from another member hitting the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684017/whats-wrong-with-maven-central-ssl-certificate?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Is there any clear Stack Overflow position between the two options for with this type of question:

1. This question has nothing to do with Stack Overflow, I should never have posted it. If I had done proper research before, I would have been able to find the Maven trouble report on the sonatype site. After the issue issue peak, which drew a few votes on this question, it will actually never be useful to anybody on Stack Overflow. This is not even a programming question, even if nobody other than a developer would encounter the problem and ask the question.
2. As a temporary problem, there was no chance I could find an answer on Google. Asking the question on Stack Overflow was the quickest way for me to find the reason for my problem, a work around and the link to a page with the core reason. Stack Overflow is a place for programmers to get help on real issues from their peers. This was a real issue and I got help from my peers in the quickest way I could.

Comment: *"This is not even a programming question"* - it's about a tool primarily used by programmers, which *is* on topic. *"SO is a place for programmers to get help"* - no, that's a side effect, it's a Q&A site. As you point out, the Q and any As become redundant pretty quickly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe are questions about "sending a twit in twitter" on topic on SO? Twitter is a tool primarily used by programmers, don't you know?

Comment: @Braiam over the API, possibly. Otherwise no. And I'd disagree that Twitter's *primarily* used by programmers!

Comment: @jonrsharpe lets use Firefox, then... or vim, or emacs, or nginx, or apache or make! The important part here is that just because it's a tool used by programmers *is not enough* to make it on topic, unless it's a question [*unique to software development*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) then all bets are off. Otherwise we should accept all the questions about people compiling random stuff and having problems.

Comment: "Asking the question on Stack Overflow was the quickest way for me to find the reason for my problem" I think that searching is the fastest way to find solution to problems, then consulting the manual, checking with the developers, and then your ol' pal the Rubber Duck. If nothing at all helps, [then you can ask on SO.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/792066)

Comment: @Braiam I'm not saying that any question about Maven is on topic, I'm saying that it being about Maven doesn't make it *a priori* **off**-topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, I interpreted it as "as long as it's maven it's on topic". Sorry.